How to Create a Custom WooCommerce Settings Page for Bulk Discount Application with 400 Bad Request Error?
I am trying to create a custom settings page for my WooCommerce-based site to apply bulk discounts to products within specified categories and brands for a defined date range. However, I'm encountering an issue where the form redirects to /wp-admin/admin-post.php and returns a 400 Bad Request error.
I've enabled DEBUG mode, but there are no error messages displayed in the logs. The only indication of an issue is a 'WordPress Error' title in the browser.
Result Page;

Here are some details about what I've implemented:

The form structure and fields
How I'm processing the form submission
Any relevant code snippets

SettingsPage;
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
class StoreSettingsPage {

private $onsale;

public function __construct()
{
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'wootemasi_store_settings_page' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'store_init' ) );
    
    add_action('admin_post_save_wootemasi_onsale_settings', array($this, 'save_settings'));
}

public function wootemasi_store_settings_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 
        'wootemasi-settings', 
        __('Toplu Ürün Yönetimi', 'wootemasi'),
        __('Ürün Yönetimi', 'wootemasi'),
        'manage_options', 
        'wootemasi-store-settings', 
        array($this, 'wootemasi_store_page')
    ); 
}

public function wootemasi_store_page() {
    
    // Check required user capability
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( esc_html__( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.', 'wootemasi' ) );
    }

    // Güncelleme işlemine ait bildirim
    if (isset($_GET['updated']) && $_GET['updated'] == 'true') {
        add_settings_error('wootemasi_messages', 'wootemasi_message', __('İndirim başarıyla uygulandı.', 'wootemasi'), 'updated');
    }       
    
    // Set class property
    $this->onsale = get_option( 'wootemasi_onsale_settings' );
    
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e('Ürün ve Mağaza Yönetimi', 'wootemasi'); ?></h2>           
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>
        
        <?php
        $active_tab = isset($_GET["tab"]) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET["tab"]) : "onsale-settings";
        ?>

        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="?page=wootemasi-store-settings&tab=onsale-settings" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab === 'onsale-settings' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">
                <?php echo __('İndirim Ayarları', 'wootemasi'); ?>
            </a>                
            <a href="?page=wootemasi-store-settings&tab=import-settings" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab === 'import-settings' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">
                <?php echo __('Toplu Ürün Yükleme', 'wootemasi'); ?>
            </a>
            <a href="?page=wootemasi-store-settings&tab=export-settings" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab === 'export-settings' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">
                <?php echo __('Toplu Ürün Çıkarma', 'wootemasi'); ?>
            </a>                
        </h2>            
        <div class="bsinternet_custom_page">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_wootemasi_onsale_settings">
        <?php
        switch ($active_tab) {
            case 'onsale-settings':
                settings_fields( 'onsale_settings_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'onsale-settings-page' );  
                break;              
            default:
                settings_fields( 'onsale_settings_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'onsale-settings-page' );
                break;
        }
        wp_nonce_field('onsale_settings_group-options');
        submit_button(__('İndirimi Uygula', 'wootemasi'));
        ?>
        </form>
        </div>
        <style>
            .bsinternet_custom_page select,
            .w100 {width: 100% !important;}
        </style>
    </div>
    <?php        
}

public function store_init() {    
    
    register_setting( 'onsale_settings_group', 'wootemasi_onsale_settings', array( $this, 'sanitize' ) );
    add_settings_section( 'wootemasi_onsale_section', __('İndirim Yönetimi', 'wootemasi'), array( $this, 'wootemasi_onsale_section' ), 'onsale-settings-page' );

    add_settings_field( 'urun_kategorisi', __('Kategori', 'wootemasi'), array( $this, 'onsale_kategori_html' ), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section' );    
    add_settings_field( 'urun_markasi', __('Üretici / Marka', 'wootemasi'), array( $this, 'onsale_marka_html' ), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section' );
    add_settings_field('baslangic_tarihi', __('Başlangıç Tarihi', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_baslangic_tarihi_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');
    add_settings_field('bitis_tarihi', __('Bitiş Tarihi', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_bitis_tarihi_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');  
    add_settings_field('indirim_turu', __('İndirim Türü', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_indirim_turu_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');
    add_settings_field('indirim_degeri', __('İndirim Değeri', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_indirim_degeri_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');
    add_settings_field('mevcut_indirimler', __('Mevcut İndirimler', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_mevcut_indirimler_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');
}

public function sanitize( $input ) {
    $sanitized_input = array();
    
    if( isset( $input['urun_kategorisi'] ) ) { $sanitized_input['urun_kategorisi'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['urun_kategorisi'] ); }
    if( isset( $input['urun_markasi'] ) ) { $sanitized_input['urun_markasi'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['urun_markasi'] ); }
    if (isset( $input['baslangic_tarihi'])) { $sanitized_input['baslangic_tarihi'] = sanitize_text_field($input['baslangic_tarihi']); }
    if (isset( $input['bitis_tarihi'])) { $sanitized_input['bitis_tarihi'] = sanitize_text_field($input['bitis_tarihi']); }
    if (isset( $input['indirim_turu'])) { $sanitized_input['indirim_turu'] = sanitize_text_field($input['indirim_turu']); }
    if (isset( $input['indirim_degeri'])) { $sanitized_input['indirim_degeri'] = sanitize_text_field($input['indirim_degeri']); }
    if (isset( $input['mevcut_indirimler'])) { $sanitized_input['mevcut_indirimler'] = sanitize_text_field($input['mevcut_indirimler']); }
    
    return $sanitized_input;    
}

public function wootemasi_onsale_section() {
    print( __('Ürünlere indirim uygulama sayfası', 'wootemasi') );
}

public function onsale_kategori_html() {
    $options = get_option('wootemasi_onsale_settings');
    $selected = isset($options['urun_kategorisi']) ? $options['urun_kategorisi'] : '';

    $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories(array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'product_cat',
        'orderby'         => 'name',
        'hide_empty'      => false,
        'hierarchical'    => true,
        'echo'            => false,
        'show_option_none'=> 'Seçiniz',
        'option_none_value' => '',
        'selected'        => $selected,
        'name'            => 'wootemasi_onsale_settings[urun_kategorisi]'
    ));

    echo $dropdown;
}

public function onsale_marka_html() {
    $options = get_option('wootemasi_onsale_settings');
    $selected = isset($options['urun_markasi']) ? $options['urun_markasi'] : '';

    $brands = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'brands',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ));

    if (!empty($brands) && !is_wp_error($brands)) {
        $dropdown = '<select name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[urun_markasi]" id="product-brand" class="w100">';
        $dropdown .= '<option value="">Marka Seçiniz</option>';

        foreach ($brands as $brand) {
            $dropdown .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($brand->slug) . '" ' . selected($selected, $brand->slug, false) . '>' . esc_html($brand->name) . '</option>';
        }

        $dropdown .= '</select>';

        echo $dropdown;
    }
}

public function onsale_baslangic_tarihi_html() {
    printf(
        '<input type="date" id="baslangic_tarihi" name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[baslangic_tarihi]" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->onsale['baslangic_tarihi'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->onsale['baslangic_tarihi']) : ''
    );      
}

public function onsale_bitis_tarihi_html() {
    printf(
        '<input type="date" id="bitis_tarihi" name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[bitis_tarihi]" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->onsale['bitis_tarihi'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->onsale['bitis_tarihi']) : ''
    );  
}

public function onsale_indirim_turu_html() {
     printf(
         '<select name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[indirim_turu]" id="indirim-turu" class="w100"><option value="yuzde">Yüzde İndirim</option><option value="sabit">Sabit İndirim</option></select>'
    );
}

public function onsale_indirim_degeri_html() {
    printf(
        '<input type="text" id="indirim_degeri" name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[indirim_degeri]" value="%s">',
        isset( $this->onsale['indirim_degeri'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->onsale['indirim_degeri']) : ''
    );  
}

public function onsale_mevcut_indirimler_html() {
     printf(
         '<select name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[mevcut_indirimler]" id="mevcut-indirimler" class="w100"><option value="dokunma">Oldukları Gibi Kalsın</option><option value="degistir">Bu Değerlerle Güncelle</option></select>'
    );
}   

public function save_settings() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'));
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['_wpnonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'onsale_settings_group-options')) {
        wp_die(__('Security check failed', 'wootemasi'));
    }       

    check_admin_referer('onsale_settings_group-options');

    $options = get_option('wootemasi_onsale_settings');
    $new_options = isset($_POST['wootemasi_onsale_settings']) ? $_POST['wootemasi_onsale_settings'] : array();
    $options = wp_parse_args($new_options, $options);

    update_option('wootemasi_onsale_settings', $options);

    $this->apply_discount_to_products();

    wp_redirect(add_query_arg(array('page' => 'wootemasi-store-settings&tab=onsale-settings', 'updated' => 'true'), admin_url('admin.php')));
    //exit; 
}   

function apply_discount_to_products() {
    $options = get_option('wootemasi_onsale_settings');

    // Kriterleri al
    $category = isset($options['urun_kategorisi']) ? $options['urun_kategorisi'] : '';
    $brand = isset($options['urun_markasi']) ? $options['urun_markasi'] : '';
    $start_date = isset($options['baslangic_tarihi']) ? strtotime($options['baslangic_tarihi']) : '';
    $end_date = isset($options['bitis_tarihi']) ? strtotime($options['bitis_tarihi']) : '';
    $discount_type = isset($options['indirim_turu']) ? $options['indirim_turu'] : '';
    $discount_value = isset($options['indirim_degeri']) ? floatval($options['indirim_degeri']) : 0;
    $existing_discounts = isset($options['mevcut_indirimler']) ? $options['mevcut_indirimler'] : 'dokunma';

    // Ürünleri sorgula
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(),
    );

    if (!empty($category)) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category,
        );
    }

    if (!empty($brand)) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brands',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $brand,
        );
    }

    $products = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($products->have_posts()) {
        while ($products->have_posts()) {
            $products->the_post();
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

            // Mevcut indirimleri kontrol et
            $current_sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
            if ($current_sale_price && $existing_discounts === 'dokunma') {
                continue; // Bu ürünü atla
            }

            $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
            $new_sale_price = $regular_price;

            if ($discount_type === 'yuzde') {
                $new_sale_price = $regular_price * (1 - ($discount_value / 100));
            } elseif ($discount_type === 'sabit') {
                $new_sale_price = $regular_price - $discount_value;
            }

            $new_sale_price = max(0, $new_sale_price); // Negatif fiyatları önle

            // Fiyatı güncelle
            $product->set_sale_price($new_sale_price);
            $product->set_date_on_sale_from($start_date);
            $product->set_date_on_sale_to($end_date);
            $product->save();
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}   
}
return new StoreSettingsPage();


I wrote it as follows. It's working.
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 * WooTemasi Store Options
 *
 * @author   WooTemasi
 * @since    1.0
 * @package  wootemasi
 */

class StoreSettingsPage
{
    /**
     * Array of custom settings/options
     */
    private $onsale;
 
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'wootemasi_store_settings_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'store_init' ) );
        add_action('wp_ajax_apply_discount', array($this, 'ajax_apply_discount'));
    }
    
    public function ajax_apply_discount() {
        check_ajax_referer('apply_discount_nonce', 'security');

        if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
            wp_send_json_error('Yetersiz yetki');
        }

        $updated_count = $this->apply_discount_to_products($_POST);
        wp_send_json_success(array(
            'message' => sprintf(__('%d ürün güncellendi.', 'wootemasi'), $updated_count)
        ));
    }
 
    /**
     * Add settings page
     * The page will appear in "Settings" menu dropdown
     */
    public function wootemasi_store_settings_page() {
        add_submenu_page( 
            'wootemasi-settings', 
            __('Toplu Ürün Yönetimi', 'wootemasi'),
            __('Ürün Yönetimi', 'wootemasi'),
            'manage_options', 
            'wootemasi-store-settings', 
            array($this, 'wootemasi_store_page')
        ); 
    }
 
    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    public function wootemasi_store_page() {
        
        // Check required user capability
        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
            wp_die( esc_html__( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.', 'wootemasi' ) );
        }       
        
        // Set class property
        $this->onsale = get_option( 'wootemasi_onsale_settings' );
        
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2><?php _e('Ürün ve Mağaza Yönetimi', 'wootemasi'); ?></h2>           
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>
            
            <?php
            $active_tab = isset($_GET["tab"]) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET["tab"]) : "onsale-settings";
            ?>

            <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
                <a href="?page=wootemasi-store-settings&tab=onsale-settings" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab === 'onsale-settings' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">
                    <?php echo __('İndirim Ayarları', 'wootemasi'); ?>
                </a>                
            </h2>  
            <?php
            if($active_tab == 'onsale-settings') : ?>
            <div class="bsinternet_custom_page">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>">
                    <?php
                    settings_fields( 'onsale_settings_group' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'onsale-settings-page' );  
                    //submit_button(__('İndirimi Uygula', 'wootemasi')); 
                    ?>
                    <button type="button" id="onSaleButton" class="button button-primary">
                        Fiyatları Güncelle
                    </button>                   
                </form>
                <style>
                    .bsinternet_custom_page select,
                    .w100 {width: 100% !important;}
                    .preloader {
                        display: none;
                        position: fixed;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
                        z-index: 9999;
                    }
                    .preloader:after {
                        content: '';
                        display: block;
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 48%;
                        top: 40%;
                        width: 40px;
                        height: 40px;
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-color: #000;
                        border-top-color: transparent;
                        border-width: 4px;
                        border-radius: 50%;
                        -webkit-animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
                        animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
                    }
                    @keyframes spin {
                        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
                        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
                    }
                </style>
                <div id="discountPreloader" class="preloader"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        $('#onSaleButton').on('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var $button = $(this);
                            $button.prop('disabled', true);
                            $('#discountPreloader').show();

                            var formData = {
                                action: 'apply_discount',
                                security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("apply_discount_nonce"); ?>',
                                urun_kategorisi: $('#product-category').val(),
                                urun_markasi: $('#product-brand').val(),
                                baslangic_tarihi: $('#baslangic_tarihi').val(),
                                bitis_tarihi: $('#bitis_tarihi').val(),
                                indirim_turu: $('#indirim-turu').val(),
                                indirim_degeri: $('#indirim_degeri').val(),
                                mevcut_indirimler: $('#mevcut-indirimler').val()
                            };

                            $.ajax({
                                url: ajaxurl,
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: formData,
                                success: function(response) {
                                    if (response.success) {
                                        alert('İndirim başarıyla uygulandı! ' + response.data.message);
                                    } else {
                                        alert('Hata oluştu: ' + response.data);
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    alert('Bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyin.');
                                },
                                complete: function() {
                                    $button.prop('disabled', false);
                                    $('#discountPreloader').hide();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>               
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php        
    }
    
    /**
     * Register and add settings
     * Sayfaların içerikleri
     */    
    public function store_init() {    
        
        /*
         * İndirim Yönetimi
         */        
        register_setting( 'onsale_settings_group', 'wootemasi_onsale_settings', array( $this, 'sanitize' ) );
        add_settings_section( 'wootemasi_onsale_section', __('İndirim Yönetimi', 'wootemasi'), array( $this, 'wootemasi_onsale_section' ), 'onsale-settings-page' );

        add_settings_field( 'urun_kategorisi', __('Kategori', 'wootemasi'), array( $this, 'onsale_kategori_html' ), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section' );    
        add_settings_field( 'urun_markasi', __('Üretici / Marka', 'wootemasi'), array( $this, 'onsale_marka_html' ), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section' );
        add_settings_field('baslangic_tarihi', __('Başlangıç Tarihi', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_baslangic_tarihi_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');
        add_settings_field('bitis_tarihi', __('Bitiş Tarihi', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_bitis_tarihi_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');  
        add_settings_field('indirim_turu', __('İndirim Türü', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_indirim_turu_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');
        add_settings_field('indirim_degeri', __('İndirim Değeri', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_indirim_degeri_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');
        add_settings_field('mevcut_indirimler', __('Mevcut İndirimler', 'wootemasi'), array($this, 'onsale_mevcut_indirimler_html'), 'onsale-settings-page', 'wootemasi_onsale_section');   
    }
 
    /**
     * Sanitize POST data from custom settings form
     *
     * @param array $input Contains custom settings which are passed when saving the form
     */
    public function sanitize( $input ) {
        $sanitized_input = array();
        
        /*
         * İndirim Sayfası Görünümü
         */     
        if( isset( $input['urun_kategorisi'] ) ) { $sanitized_input['urun_kategorisi'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['urun_kategorisi'] ); }
        if( isset( $input['urun_markasi'] ) ) { $sanitized_input['urun_markasi'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['urun_markasi'] ); }
        if (isset( $input['baslangic_tarihi'])) { $sanitized_input['baslangic_tarihi'] = sanitize_text_field($input['baslangic_tarihi']); }
        if (isset( $input['bitis_tarihi'])) { $sanitized_input['bitis_tarihi'] = sanitize_text_field($input['bitis_tarihi']); }
        if (isset( $input['indirim_turu'])) { $sanitized_input['indirim_turu'] = sanitize_text_field($input['indirim_turu']); }
        if (isset( $input['indirim_degeri'])) { $sanitized_input['indirim_degeri'] = sanitize_text_field($input['indirim_degeri']); }
        if (isset( $input['mevcut_indirimler'])) { $sanitized_input['mevcut_indirimler'] = sanitize_text_field($input['mevcut_indirimler']); }
        
        return $sanitized_input;    
    }
    
    /** 
     * İndirim
     */
    public function wootemasi_onsale_section() {
        print( __('Ürünlere indirim uygulama sayfası', 'wootemasi') );
    }
    
    public function onsale_kategori_html() {
        $options = get_option('wootemasi_onsale_settings');
        $selected = isset($options['urun_kategorisi']) ? $options['urun_kategorisi'] : '';

        $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'id'              => 'product-category',
            'taxonomy'        => 'product_cat',
            'orderby'         => 'name',
            'hide_empty'      => false,
            'hierarchical'    => true,
            'echo'            => false,
            'show_option_none'=> 'Seçiniz',
            'option_none_value' => '',
            'selected'        => $selected,
            'value_field'     => 'slug',
            'name'            => 'wootemasi_onsale_settings[urun_kategorisi]'
        ));

        echo $dropdown;
    }

    public function onsale_marka_html() {
        $options = get_option('wootemasi_onsale_settings');
        $selected = isset($options['urun_markasi']) ? $options['urun_markasi'] : '';

        $brands = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'brands',
            'hide_empty' => true,
        ));

        if (!empty($brands) && !is_wp_error($brands)) {
            $dropdown = '<select name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[urun_markasi]" id="product-brand" class="w100">';
            $dropdown .= '<option value="">Marka Seçiniz</option>';

            foreach ($brands as $brand) {
                $dropdown .= '<option value="' . esc_attr($brand->slug) . '" ' . selected($selected, $brand->slug, false) . '>' . esc_html($brand->name) . '</option>';
            }

            $dropdown .= '</select>';

            echo $dropdown;
        }
    }
    
    public function onsale_baslangic_tarihi_html() {
        printf(
            '<input type="date" id="baslangic_tarihi" name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[baslangic_tarihi]" value="%s">',
            isset( $this->onsale['baslangic_tarihi'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->onsale['baslangic_tarihi']) : ''
        );      
    }

    public function onsale_bitis_tarihi_html() {
        printf(
            '<input type="date" id="bitis_tarihi" name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[bitis_tarihi]" value="%s">',
            isset( $this->onsale['bitis_tarihi'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->onsale['bitis_tarihi']) : ''
        );  
    }
    
    public function onsale_indirim_turu_html() {
         printf(
             '<select name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[indirim_turu]" id="indirim-turu" class="w100"><option value="yuzde">Yüzde İndirim</option><option value="sabit">Sabit İndirim</option></select>'
        );
    }
    
    public function onsale_indirim_degeri_html() {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="indirim_degeri" name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[indirim_degeri]" value="%s">',
            isset( $this->onsale['indirim_degeri'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->onsale['indirim_degeri']) : ''
        );  
    }
    
    public function onsale_mevcut_indirimler_html() {
         printf(
             '<select name="wootemasi_onsale_settings[mevcut_indirimler]" id="mevcut-indirimler" class="w100"><option value="dokunma">Oldukları Gibi Kalsın</option><option value="degistir">Bu Değerlerle Güncelle</option></select>'
        );
    }
    
    /**
     * İndirim İşlemi
     */ 
    public function apply_discount_to_products($data) {
        // AJAX'tan gelen verileri kullan
        $category = isset($data['urun_kategorisi']) ? sanitize_text_field($data['urun_kategorisi']) : '';
        $brand = isset($data['urun_markasi']) ? sanitize_text_field($data['urun_markasi']) : '';
        $discount_type = isset($data['indirim_turu']) ? sanitize_text_field($data['indirim_turu']) : '';
        $discount_value = isset($data['indirim_degeri']) ? floatval($data['indirim_degeri']) : 0;
        $start_date = isset($data['baslangic_tarihi']) ? sanitize_text_field($data['baslangic_tarihi']) : '';
        $end_date = isset($data['bitis_tarihi']) ? sanitize_text_field($data['bitis_tarihi']) : '';
        $existing_discounts = isset($data['mevcut_indirimler']) ? sanitize_text_field($data['mevcut_indirimler']) : '';

        error_log("Applying discount: Category: $category, Brand: $brand, Type: $discount_type, Value: $discount_value, Start: $start_date, End: $end_date, Existing: $existing_discounts");

        // Ürünleri sorgula
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array('relation' => 'AND'),
        );

        if (!empty($category)) {
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category,
            );
        }

        if (!empty($brand)) {
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'brands',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $brand,
            );
        }

        $products = new WP_Query($args);
        $updated_count = 0;

        if ($products->have_posts()) {
            while ($products->have_posts()) {
                $products->the_post();
                $product_id = get_the_ID();
                $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

                $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                $current_sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();

                // Mevcut indirimleri kontrol et
                if ($existing_discounts === 'dokunma' && !empty($current_sale_price)) {
                    continue; // Mevcut indirimi olan ürünleri atla
                }

                $new_sale_price = $regular_price;

                if ($discount_type === 'yuzde') {
                    $new_sale_price = $regular_price * (1 - ($discount_value / 100));
                } elseif ($discount_type === 'sabit') {
                    $new_sale_price = $regular_price - $discount_value;
                }

                $new_sale_price = max(0, $new_sale_price); // Negatif fiyatları önle

                // Fiyatı güncelle
                $product->set_sale_price($new_sale_price);
                $product->set_date_on_sale_from($start_date);
                $product->set_date_on_sale_to($end_date);
                $product->save();

                $updated_count++;
            }
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $updated_count;
    }
}

return new StoreSettingsPage(); 


Some explanation here of what you changed from the code above, and why, is necessary, I think.

I rewrote the code using Ajax. So a lot of things changed.

And... a good answer would explain those things.
